# System of two variables quadratic equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-equations

Let $\mathcal{P}_{2,Z}$ be the set of all 2 variables quadratic equations $P(x,y)$ with integral coefficients: $$P(x,y)=a_1x^2+a_2y^2+a_3xy+a_4x+a_5y+a_6\ \ \ \ \ \ (a_i\in \mathbb{Z})$$
Consider a system of of $n$ equations:
$$\begin{cases}
P_1(x_1,x_2)=0\\\
P_2(x_2,x_3)=0\\\
...\\\
P_n(x_n,x_1)=0\\\
\end{cases} \ \ \ \ \ \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ P_i(x_i,x_{i+1})\in \mathcal{P}_{2,Z};\ \  P_i(x_i,x_{i+1}) \text{ has real roots}.$$
Can we have some constrains of coefficients of $P_i$ such that the system has no real root?

Do you know some work or related materials about this problem? Thank you so much.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking for a description of the open subset $U$ of `$\mathcal{P}_{2,Z}^n$` parameterizing systems with no real root?  Of course `$U$` contains `$V^n$` where `$V$` is the open subset of `$\mathcal{P}_{2,Z}$` parameterizing conics with no real points.  I believe that $V$ is the open subset where each of `$a_1D$`, `$a_2D$` and `$a_6D$` are positive, where $D$ is the discriminant: `$D=4a_1a_2a_6+a_3a_4a_5-(a_1a_5^2 + a_2a_4^2+a_6a_3^2)$`.

Comment: Actually . . . the open set $U$ contains the union from $i=1,\dots,n$ of the inverse image of $V$ under the projection $\pi_i:\mathcal{P}^n_{2,Z}\to \mathcal{P}_{2,Z}$ onto the $i^{\text{th}}$ factor.  If *any* of the equations in the system is inconsistent, then the whole system is inconsistent.  

Comment: Thank for your suggestion, but in my problem, every P_i has many real roots. I forgot to write that.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question.  What *precisely* are you asking?